After switching from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04: Facing an issue while Running Previous React Native Projects
I've been working with React Native for a year now. Previously, I was using Windows, but I recently switched to Ubuntu and intend to stick with it. The reason for the switch is that Windows was somewhat laggy and took a lot of time to generate builds. I've configured the environment according to the instructions in the React Native documentation. The project runs properly and the app installs on the device, but after loading, it displays a strange error screen (screenshot attached). I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue, as I've been stuck on it for a week.

ERROR  Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'RNSModule':
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library
"librnscreens.so" not found, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module
method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as
callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace,
JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog,
RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter,
GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient,
RCTEventEmitter. A frequent cause of the error is that the application
entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle
is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading
React Native., js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module
method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as
callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace,
JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog,
RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter,
GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient,
RCTEventEmitter. A frequent cause of the error is that the application
entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle
is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading
React Native., js engine: hermes


Please don't post text error messages as screenshot. Just paste the error message as text into your question and format it as code.

Updated the post with error as text.
